# Java Collection supporting FIFO & element uniqueness with constraints

Tags: java, arrays, collections, types, queue

I am working on a leisure project with others and need a Java collection type that supports FIFO (first in first out) and also only allows unique elements (elements are actually objects with an equals() method ONLY - there is no scope for a comparable() method).

I cannot implement a hashCode() method due to project constraints - the object class that the collections solution will contain cannot be edited to add any other method.

I have been searching and cannot for the life of me figure out a solution to this that does not involve a LinkedHashSet or anything that involves me editing the element object class.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the LinkedList class (or any other collection that retains order) and override the add() method(s).  In the overridded method, make your equals() check against all other items in the collection.  If it passes, call super.add().